# How to set expire cookie and auto logout Blazor server

Tags: c#, cookies, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server application. I want to implement auto-logout by setting the timer to expire cookie so that the authentication cookie is lost so I have to log in again. I've tried to do implement it in `Startup.cs`, like so:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    }
);
```

After I run the application, the timer expires and the cookies still exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just add this code into your setCookies

```
var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    IsPersistent = true,
                    RedirectUri = this.Request.Host.Value,
                    //Set Your Expire Cookie
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(10)
                };
```